# Where can I find the Java class files for Event Gateways listed in ColdFusion Administrator?

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In CF Administrator, Event Gateways > Gateway Types there is a long class name listed under the "Java Class" heading. Where is the class file for this located?

Long Class Name: `examples.ActiveMQ.JMSGateway`

> **Under Configured Coldfusion GatewayTypes**
>
> Name: ActiveMQ
>
> Description: Handles Apache ActiveMQ JMS messages
>
> Java Class: examples.ActiveMQ.JMSGateway

Where is the above class with name `examples.ActiveMQ.JMSGateway` located?

Comment: Check the `{cf9}/gateway/lib` directory? [more info here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec15849-8000.html)

Comment: Well, `C:\ColdFusion9\gateway\lib` has one `examples` executable JAR file and two properties file, that's it. Any other possibility?

Comment: What's the long class name? Might be generated from a CFC?

Comment: Please find the additional information in my updated question.

Comment: Yeah, that's in the examples.jar - open it with a zip application and you'll see the first two elements as directories containing various class files, including a JMSGateway.class file.

Comment: Thanks. this one was for ActiveMQ. Where can I find for others like SMS,SOCKET etc? I mean I saw SOCKET folder over there but not other folders.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40272/discussion-between-jack-and-peter-boughton)

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear. Please go through it once again and remove the hold.

Comment: Well Socket and all the others starting `examples.` are in the examples.jar file. The SMS one is `coldfusion.eventgateway.sms.SMSGateway` so it'll be in `{cf9}/lib/cfusion.jar` (along with all the others starting `coldfusion.`)

Comment: Taking a question off hold needs five votes (or a single mod) - it's currently got 4, so just needs one more person who can vote to see it.

Comment: Thanks. When I opened the file, it's all encrypted. I wanna see the methods defined in there. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I downloaded Java Decompiler and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Cool. Probably worth pointing out that decompiling those files _might_ be against the Adobe EULA, so depending what you're doing you may want to check up on that.

Comment: *it's all encrypted* Not encrypted, just compiled into byte code. For future reference, if you have a JDK installed, you can view the methods of a class without decompiling. 1) From a command prompt, use: `javap -cp c:\path\to\some.jar path.to.ClassName` 2) If the jar is in the class path, grab a reference to it with createObject("java", "path.to.ClassName"), then dump the object to see its methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why everyone's answering in comments instead of answers.

The JMSGateway is in `[cfusion root]/WEB-INF/cfusion/gateway/lib/examples.jar`, as people have indicated. For me, the specific dir is `C:\apps\adobe\JRun\4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\cfusion\gateway\lib\examples.jar`, which is different than the default location, as I stick my Adobe stuff in C:\apps\adobe\, rather than installing in the root of my drive.

A .jar file is just a zip, so you can open it and see the files within, however the files are binaries, not source code so "officially" will be of little use to you.

Unofficially, there are Java decompilers out there which one can use to decompile stuff:
[DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/)
[JD Project](http://jd.benow.ca/)

*However*: read your ColdFusion EULA, and understand the legalities of such activity. I am not a lawyer and am not giving advice when I make these observations, but my understanding that decompiling CF class files violates the EULA. If you're in the States this is legally enforceable; I don't think it is in the EU or elsewhere (whether Adobe might like it to be or not). And it's unlikely any action will be taken if you decompile the thing simply for your own reference and don't publicise the source code or make too much of a thing of your findings. But... like I said: this does not constitute actual legal advice, nor should you take it as encouragement to violate your EULA. I am simply saying "it's possible to decompile a class file".

Comment: re: first line - The question got locked by a trigger-happy mod, so there wasn't much choice.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, ah OK. God bless the S/O moderators.